# Why jQuery.val( value ) does not dispatch any event from the DOM element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

When we use the method `jQuery.Val( value )` over a DOM element to change its value.

Shouldn't the element dispatch an event informing that its value has changed? *-I though the event 'change' was going to be dispatched.*

If it shouldn't why?

### [Live Demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/q9yRJ/)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's not dispatched, this just doesn't happen when it's *programmatically* changed.  You are however free to fire the event when needed like this:

```
$('#Anne').val('Jenny').change();
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/q9yRJ/1/).

The reasoning?  If the *user* changed something you may need to react, but if *you* changed something then you know what happened, and firing an event handler may be completely wasteful...so it's up to you to call that event handler *if* it's needed.

Comment: @SDReyes: Also: If event handlers would fire automatically for progammatic changes, this could trigger an unavoidable infinite loop, depending on what you do. It's good that they don't.