# React event handler is not called using jquery val() method

Tags: jquery, event-handling, reactjs

**How to invoke react handler using jquery val() method?**

Below is a simple react component with input field. 
Whenever the value changes the onChange event handler is fired and 
value is  set to state of the component.

```
  var Hello = React.createClass({

   getInitialState: function(){
     return {
        val: this.props.defVal || ""
     };
   },
   onChange: function(event){

    var newVal = event.target.value;
    console.log("changed", newVal);
    this.setState({val: newVal});

   },
   render: function() {
     return <div>
     <input id = "asd" className = "asd" value = {this.state.val} onChange = {this.onChange}/>
     Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
   }

  });

  React.render(<Hello name="World" />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

However the onChange handler is not fired when i use jquery val method.
   Like $('#asd').val("asd");

Is there a way i can invoke the handler using jquery val function?

Comment: `.val()` never triggers a change event (react or otherwise). Also you should find a way to communicate with the component without using jQuery or dom.

Comment: Easier said than done when you're trying to get React and a jQuery plugin to work nicely together.

Comment: And almost three years later, this question remains unanswered :(. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49783314/trigger-change-event-for-react-rendered-input-type-range

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1.Set a `ref` on the input item, like:

```
<input id="asd" className="asd" value={this.state.val}
ref={(myInput) => { this.myInput = myInput; }/>
```

...now you can refer to `this.myInput.value` .

Than you can

2.run arbitrary code using some other event, such as onBlur:

```
<input id="asd" className="asd" value={this.state.val}
ref={(myInput) => { this.myInput = myInput; }
onBlur={this.onBlur.bind(this)} />
```

(or newer ES6 syntax for the same)

...and:

3.make a function to handle it, which uses your `ref`:

```
onBlur(e) {
    var newVal = this.myInput.value; // uses the ref
    console.log("changed", newVal);
    this.setState({val: newVal});
}
```

**NB:**

Contrary to what I've read on pages that aren't react-specific, you **can't** do:

```
$('#asd').val("asd").change();
```

...
(There's at least one such [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3961475/2308190) that got me naively excited!)