# function returning the data to filter and map that show error React.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, filter

I'm try to collect some collection  of data from Firebase. Filter map to fronted using React Js.
In below code **Firebase.database().ref('public/post/India/Tamil Nadu/SALEM/').on('value', this.getData, this.errordata)** Using  this function i get data on **this.getdata()**

I got data that show in console output but browser show error as **TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined.**
Please any one solve this

Please Note

- I successfully retrieve my data From firebase That show in console output.
- The issue while getdata function returning the data to filter and map that show error

->
Home.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Firebase from './container/Firebase';
class home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            nam: "a",
            arr:"",
            users: ['abc', "pdsa", "eccs", "koi"]
        }

    }
    componentWillMount() {

        Firebase.database().ref('public/post/India/Tamil Nadu/SALEM/').on('value', this.getData, this.errordata)
       
    }
    getData(data) {
        console.log("sdata");
        //console.log(data.val());
        
        var post = data.val();
        console.log(post);
        var keyy = Object.keys(post);
        console.log(keyy);
        var lisarr =['']  ;     
        for (var i = 0; i < keyy.length; i++) {
            var k = keyy[i];
            
            lisarr[i]={
                key :k ,
                Organisation : post[k].Organisation, 
                Role :post[k].Role
            }
        } 
        
        console.log("getData lisarr");
        console.log(lisarr);
        return lisarr;
    }
   
    errordata(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
   
    handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({ nam: event.target.value });
    };

    render() {
       
        return (
            <div>

                <h1>Homa</h1>
                
                {this.getData().filter(person => this.state.num === null ||person.Role.includes("h")).map(filteredPerson => (
        <li>
          {filteredPerson.Role}
        </li>
      ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default home;
```

Console output :

```
 getData post                                                                     home.js:24
 {-MFJqzPGXeLPk6pQzY18: {…}, -MFKZLLtWkH2arNnmNE_: {…}, -MFKZg38ybFO9hC0UqLf: {…}}- 
       -MFJqzPGXeLPk6pQzY18: {City: "SALEM", Country: "India", Description: "Proven experienc...
       -MFKZLLtWkH2arNnmNE_: {City: "SALEM", Country: "India", Description: "attend customers↵...
       -MFKZg38ybFO9hC0UqLf: {City: "SALEM", Country: "India", Description: "attend customers↵...

                                                                                     home.js:26 
 getData keyy                                                                        home.js:27 
 ["-MFJqzPGXeLPk6pQzY18", "-MFKZLLtWkH2arNnmNE_", "-MFKZg38ybFO9hC0UqLf"]
           0: "-MFJqzPGXeLPk6pQzY18"
           1: "-MFKZLLtWkH2arNnmNE_"
           2: "-MFKZg38ybFO9hC0UqLf"

  getData  lisarr                                                                  home.js:45 

 (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
  0:
      Organisation: " abc CAR COMPANY PVT LTD "
      Role: "Sales Executive"
      key: "-MFJqzPGXeLPk6pQzY18"
  1:
      Organisation: "abc conseltency"
      Role: "Surgical Avenue"
      key: "-MFKZLLtWkH2arNnmNE_"

  2:
       Organisation: "Sociall.in "
       Role: "Excutive"
       key: "-MFKZg38ybFO9hC0UqLf"
```

My  browser show error as

```
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined
  19 | console.log("sdata");
  20 | //console.log(data.val());
  21 | 
> 22 | var post = data.val();
     | ^  23 | console.log(post);
  24 | var keyy = Object.keys(post);
  25 | console.log(keyy);
```

Comment: Val() is a jQuary function...... Read this , it might help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31116585/react-event-handler-is-not-called-using-jquery-val-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not passing snapshot to the function that is why it is showing undefined.
Try this out:

```
   ...
    this.state = {
    fetchedData: null,
            nam: "a",
            ...
        }
   ...
    componentDidMount() {

       Firebase.database().ref('public/post/India/Tamil Nadu/SALEM/')
        .on('value', (snapshot) => { 
            if(snapshot.val() != null){
             this.setState({fetchedData: snapshot.val());
            }else {
             this.errordata();
        }});
       
    }
...

{this.getData(this.state.fetchedData).filter(person => this.state.num === null ||person.Role.includes("h")).map(...)
```

Please refer: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events

Comment: thanking you for help to resolve . I had tried your code , But still have same error .

Comment: kindly console.log(data) instead of console.log(data.val()) in getData function and tell me what values are logged?

Comment: In My question Console Out Put  **Getdata Post** and **Console.log(data.val())** are same. I get _correct  actual value_.

Comment: **Console.log(data )  show some unknow function like**  DataSnapshot {node_: ChildrenNode, ref_: Reference, index_: PriorityIndex}
index_: PriorityIndex
__proto__: Index
compare: ƒ (a, b)
constructor: ƒ PriorityIndex()
indexedValueChanged: ƒ (oldNode, newNode)
isDefinedOn: ƒ (node)
makePost: ƒ (indexValue, name)
maxPost: ƒ ()
minPost: ƒ ()
toString: ƒ ()

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand it initially. While rendering you are calling this.getData() without any data. So while fetching from firebase either you can set the data to some state and then use this state to filter. And for this you will have to use ComponentDidMount life cycle. Hope this helps

Comment: I had attempted to set the data to some state .  But I have 3 column matrix array . `this.setdata { lisarr }`  attempted fail.  recommend any link or tutorial

Comment: Please take a look on edited posted. Also you can refer :https://sebhastian.com/react-firebase-real-time-database-guide/. Thanks.

Comment: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of null**    {this.state.fetchedData.filter(person => this.state.num === null ||person.Role.includes("h")).map(filteredPerson => ( ....

Comment: **this.state.fetchedData** is nice try . Data Structure is different. Look the above console output. Here  get data post and  this.state.fetched  are have same data structure.   But I need data structure look like in console output getdata lisarr

Comment: If I am not wrong you are filtering out of this.state.fetchedData. Try to use this.getData(this.state.fetchedData).filter(...)

Comment: I had try that show **TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of null**    console.log(this.state.fetchedData); and   console.log(fetchedData);  are **null**

Comment: I think Must change my title  have any idea

Comment: Can you please paste render() code and hope you are fetching firebase data in **`componentDidMount`** instead of componentWillMount?